# Is there any Linux distro which works in real mode?

Tags: linux, assembly

I am looking for GNU/Linux distribution which works in real mode. I want to install it in virtual machine so I can study assembly. Is there any one who can help me with it ?

Comment: On day 1 the Linux kernel required at least a 386 because it uses protected mode. To my knowledge that never changed...

Comment: Virtual machines can run protected-mode OSes just fine.

Comment: take a look at http://www.uclinux.org/ this is an MMU less Linux project. So no real mode.

Comment: Before trying to understand whole distribution, start with simple programs by compiling them with `gcc -S ...` and look at the generated assembler code.

Comment: Stop.  You're actually damaging your education by starting with 8086 code.  You will not need to use it in a modern OS, outside of the boot loader.  And there will be craptons of stuff to unlearn if you want to write stuff that works in a running 64-bit OS.

Comment: [Great assembly tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHE0txCjGgI&list=PL0C5C980A28FEE68D), this taught me assembly with knowledge at all. I suggest you watch this series to learn assembly instead of what you're trying to do now.

Answer (score 4):

There's [ELKS](http://elks.sourceforge.net/), a subset of Linux suitable for the 8086 processor (ie, no memory manager unit needed, real mode only, etc).  But I don't think that such a beast will be your best vehicle to study assembly...